# How add correct stylesheets file on heroku?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sass

I unload my application on heroku.com - and unload successfully. But I add stylesheets, and complete any commands such as `git add .` `git commit -m 'add'` and `git push heroku master` I face some problems. First I change name from application.css to application.scss.erb. But some problems appear again. Pictures contain in app/assets/images

```
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/appq$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 65, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57/57), 101.79 KiB, done.
Total 57 (delta 28), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Using rake 10.3.2
       Using minitest 5.3.5
       Using thread_safe 0.3.4
       Using builder 3.2.2
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using rack 1.5.2
       Using i18n 0.6.9
       Using mime-types 1.25.1
       Using polyglot 0.3.5
       Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Using execjs 2.2.1
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using hike 1.2.3
       Using multi_json 1.10.1
       Using pg 0.17.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Using json 1.8.1
       Using sass 3.2.19
       Using tzinfo 1.2.1
       Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
       Using treetop 1.4.15
       Using rack-test 0.6.2
       Using coffee-script 2.2.0
       Using sprockets 2.11.0
       Using rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Using rdoc 4.1.1
       Using uglifier 2.5.1
       Using activesupport 4.1.1
       Using actionview 4.1.1
       Using mail 2.5.4
       Using actionpack 4.1.1
       Using activemodel 4.1.1
       Using jbuilder 2.1.1
       Using sdoc 0.4.0
       Using actionmailer 4.1.1
       Using railties 4.1.1
       Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
       Using activerecord 4.1.1
       Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Using jquery-rails 3.1.1
       Using sass-rails 4.0.3
       Using rails 4.1.1
       Using turbolinks 2.2.2
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (1.15s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.194880 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/avator-8417efe1732a1240e96ca4537ddff902.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.196966 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/chart1-d20da096a52b8f67a4bc1ba5d4aa8f9c.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.198911 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/chart2-c80702d32a0dec4d6c4734d4e6f59423.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.200752 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/rails (другая копия)-34f56ba8d936fb280749fc72dc5e65b0.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.202422 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/rails (копия)-34f56ba8d936fb280749fc72dc5e65b0.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.204308 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/rails-34f56ba8d936fb280749fc72dc5e65b0.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.206274 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_body-6837be0a2d5e5de15c109dc58d61247a.jpg
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.208235 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_button-4a57228153ebb98dc793fd35197329cd.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.209981 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_button_hover-8a8eee02e3cf18335c8618406f4911ac.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.211660 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_comment-2b695c6a958fee2be7986f03db6e404d.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.213819 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_featured_project-70897516972dd1e34d0f37a6397b61cd.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.215771 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_featured_project_01-a579b74299cdaac7ecef96fd66c315a6.jpg
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.217726 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_footer-f37a0c82e91139e78ca9c28e2df96c6b.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.219738 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_header-90837c0eac4e3fe26328c4d0973759f1.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.221516 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_image_01-8952f44f70f51d2bdbd1d62f6c11500a.jpg
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.223261 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_image_02-f102841f2b62c6c8850ecf5f26ee9c2b.jpg
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.225076 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_list-115c5c76c19597f44465749333df442e.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.227082 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_menu-6378729d14122a4e8efbb63b144e0e96.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.229039 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_menu_hover-8b683e0697358f16a4183db29dec2d95.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.230827 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_post_bottom-b6b97935f9e5cf5e9a3db2fc0ac4e9a5.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.232589 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_rss-66031ff333b20192724f3407be964e9c.png
       I, [2014-06-27T19:38:47.234406 #720]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/public/assets/templatemo_wrapper-3708945d2fa61cc622dc666e8d738799.png
       rake aborted!
       Sprockets::CircularDependencyError: /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:392:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:37:in `init_with'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:24:in `from_hash'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:54:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_a1269278-1141-499d-a732-aced45457a52/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:mighty-oasis-6099.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mighty-oasis-6099.git'
```

**application.scss.css**

```
.picture:rollover {
    backgound-image: image-url("chart1.png");
}

.picture:rollover:hover {
    backgound-image: url("chart2.png");
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #666;
    font-family: Helevetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    background-image: url("templatemo_body.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CC0000;
}

a:hover {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

p { margin: 0px; padding: 0 0 10px 0; }
img { border: none; }

h1 { font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 0 30px 0; padding: 5px 0; color: #000; }
h2 { font-size: 28px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 28px; margin: 0 0 30px 0; padding: 0; color: #c7a902; }
h3 { font-size: 21px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 0; padding: 0; color: #666666; }
h4 { font-size: 18px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 0; color: #ffa200; }
h5 { font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 0; color: #ffa200;}
h6 { font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 5px 0; padding: 0; color: #ffa200;}

.cleaner { clear: both; width: 100%; height: 0px; font-size: 0px;  }
.cleaner_h10 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 10px; }
.cleaner_h20 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 20px; }
.cleaner_h30 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 30px; }
.cleaner_h40 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 40px; }
.cleaner_h50 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 50px; }
.cleaner_h60 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 60px; }

.margin_r30 { margin-right: 30px; }

.vertical_divider { border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; }
.horizon_divider {  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; }

.float_l {
    float: left;
}

.float_r {
    float: right;
}

.image_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fl_img {
    float: left;
    margin: 3px 30px 15px 0;
}
.fr_img {
    float: right;
    margin: 3px 0 15px 30px;
}

blockquote { font-style: italic; margin-left: 10px;}
cite { font-weight: bold; }
cite span { color: #8da332; }
em { color: #5d6d1e; }

.templatemo_list {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.templatemo_list li {
    background: transparent url("templatemo_list.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0px;
    margin:0 0 20px;
    padding:0 0 0 25px;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.templatemo_list li a {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.templatemo_list li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.button a {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 82px;
    height: 23px;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: url("templatemo_button.png") no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: url("templatemo_button_hover.png") no-repeat;
}

#templatemo_wrapper {
    width: 970px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("templatemo_wrapper.png") repeat-y;
}

/* menu */

#templatemo_menu {
    width: 830px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 100px;
    padding: 20px 30px 0 0;
    background: url("templatemo_menu.png") top repeat-x;
}

#templatemo_menu ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 112px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0 ;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e4decd;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

#templatemo_menu ul li a:hover, #templatemo_menu ul li .current {
    height: 38px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background: url("templatemo_menu_hover.png") bottom no-repeat;
}

/* end of menu */

#templatemo_left_column {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

#templatemo_right_column {
    float: right;
    width: 520px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#templatemo_header {
    width: 360px;
    height: 276px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background: url("templatemo_header.png") left center no-repeat;
}

#templatemo_header  #site_title {
    float: left;
    width: 310px;
    padding: 115px 0 0 60px;
}

#templatemo_header  #site_title h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#templatemo_header  #site_title h1 a {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#templatemo_header  #site_title h1 strong {
    color: #f00;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#templatemo_header  #site_title a span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#featured_project {
    float: right;
    width: 520px;
    height: 210px;
    padding: 33px 0;
    background: url("templatemo_featured_project.png") no-repeat;
}

#templatemo_sidebar {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}

#templatemo_main {
    float: right;
    width: 490px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.post_section {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 60px 10px 0;
    margin: 40px 0;
    background: url("templatemo_post_bottom.png") bottom left no-repeat;
}

.post_section h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.post_section p {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.post_section img {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.post_section .comment {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: url("templatemo_comment.png") no-repeat;
}

.post_section .comment a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post_section .comment_tab {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #666;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#templatemo_rss a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 60px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #ffa200;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url("templatemo_rss.png") left center no-repeat;
}

#templatemo_header #templatemo_rss a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#templatemo_rss a span {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.comment_tab {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #666;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#comment_section {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 460px;
}

.first_level {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.comments {
    list-style: none;
}

.comments li { margin-bottom: 10px; list-style:none; }
.comments li .commentbox1 { border: 1px solid #dddddd;  background: #eeeeee; }
.comments li .commentbox2 { border: 1px solid #dddddd;  background: #f6f6f6; }
.comments li .comment_box { clear: both; width:100%; padding: 15px;  }
.comment_box .gravatar { float: left; width: 50px; margin-right: 15px; background: #fff; }
.comment_box .gravatar img { margin: 0; width: 50px; height: 50px; }
.comment_box .comment_text { margin: 0 0 0 65px; }

.comment_box .comment_text p { margin: 0; }
.comment_text .comment_author { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #781919; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.comment_text .date { font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; color: #333; padding-left: 10px; }
.comment_text .time { font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; color: #333; padding-left: 10px; }
.comment_text .reply a { display: block; clear: both; float: right; padding: 1px 10px; height: 24px; text-align: center; background: #3694ab; border: 1px solid #fff; color: #fff; }


#comment_form {
    clear: both;
}

#comment_form h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#comment_form form {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#comment_form textarea {
    background:#FFFFFF none repeat fixed 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display:block;
    font-size:1.1em;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:5px;
    width: 360px;
}

#comment_form .form_row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#comment_form form input {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    background:#FFFFFF none repeat fixed 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#comment_form .submit_btn {
    width: 80px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    color: #666666;
}

.service_box {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.service_box .left {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.service_box .left img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.service_box .right {
    float: right;
    width: 360px;
}

.service_box ol li {
    list-style: decimal-leading-zero;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.service_box ol li a {
    color: #058edc;
}

/* gallery */
#gallery {
    clear: both;
}

#gallery a {
    border: none;
}
#gallery ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#gallery ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

#gallery ul li .left {
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
}

#gallery ul li .left img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 110px;
    border: none;
    border: 5px solid #d4cbaf;
}

#gallery ul li .right {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
}

#gallery ul li .right button {
    margin: 0;
}

/* end of gallery */

#contact_form form {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#contact_form form .input_field {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#contact_form form label {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#contact_form form textarea {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#contact_form form .submit_btn {
    margin-left: 110px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    color: #666666;
}

/* footer */

#templatemo_footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 860px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 100px;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: image-url("templatemo_footer.png");
}

#templatemo_footer a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#body_content_title{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual contents of your application.css file.

Comment: The circular dependency suggest that you have a reference to itself in that file.  Deleting the file is not necessarily the solution

Comment: I add scss.css file in my post

Comment: I should delete my css file? And create it again?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to delete app/assets/stylesheets/application.css to fix the problem and resolve the issue.

Comment: And again create this file?

Answer (score 0):

**Circular Dependency**

Here's your error:

> Sprockets::CircularDependencyError

Circular Dependency basically means this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/* = require application */
```

When you include [dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28project_management%29) in an application (can be any application), you have to ensure they are completely independent, so they don't conflict with the application itself. A circular dependency basically means one of the assets you're importing / requiring is being called both by your application & the dependency, creating an infinite loop

The way to fix this is to remove the reference to the dependency from either your application, or any asset you have control over

--

**Error**

Your error will likely the result of this:

> First I change name from application.css to application.scss.erb

The problem will almost certainly be with how you're calling `application.css.scss` & its dependencies. Your `application.css.scss` (change your `application.scss.css` to `application.css.scss`) file does not give any indication of a circular loop, however, I would make sure you are not referencing any external files inside it